# Accessing session data in another controller gives error

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session-variables, codeigniter-3

```
public function LoginUser()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else 
    {

        $data['Email']=$this->input->post('email');
        $data['Password']=$this->input->post('password');
        $result=$this->UserAccount_model->LoginUser($data);
        if($result)
        {

            $session_data = array(
            'sesid' => $result[0]->id,
            'sesname' => $result[0]->Name,
            'sesemail' => $result[0]->Email);

            // Add user data in session
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

            $url=base_url()."UserAccount/LoggedIn";

              header("Location:$url");
         }
```

**Now i am accessing session data in photo controller**

```
public function LikePhoto()
{
    $Id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $UserId=$this->$session_data['sesid'];
    print($UserId);
    exit();
```

*but this gives error*

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: session_data
>
> Filename: controllers/Photo.php
>
> Line Number: 55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CI to get session data you have to use `$this->session->userdata()`

So change your code  to:

```
$UserId=$this->session->userdata('logged_in')['sesid'];
```

**EDIT** If you want to store data from array only add array variable in session

So change

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
```

To

```
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

And to retrieve :

```
$UserId=$this->session->userdata('sesid');
```

Comment: Should it be not `logged_in` instead `sesid` like this `$this->session->userdata('logged_in')['sesid']`

Comment: For that also have to change `set_userdata`. See update @user2486

Comment: Ok you made the changes